# Python: Getting local file path from request.files

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I need help uploading a file directly from an HTML form to an API. I've seen this being done for remote URLs, but I don't know how to do this for local files? I tried writing this, but its not working:

```py
uploadmedia = request.files['fileupload']
client = Client('thisismykey')
with open(uploadmedia, 'rb') as file:
  new_upload = client.uploads('<space-id>').create(file)
```

The line `client.uploads` is what is specified in the API docs [here](https://github.com/contentful/contentful-management.py#uploads). I just need to be able to get the file path.

The comments suggest the following:

```
# you can use either a file-like object or a path.
# If you use a path, the SDK will open it, create the upload and
# close the file afterwards.
```

I am assuming that `request.files['fileupload']` is a file like object, so I just passed that along.

The above code gives me the following error:

```
File "D:\Gatsby\submission\flask-tailwindcss-starter\app\__init__.py", line 28, in index
with open(uploadmedia, 'rb') as file:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not FileStorage
```

I know that in this example, `uploadmedia.filename` would get me the file's name, but what is the attribute for the path? How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `request.files['file']` is an instance of a [FileStorage](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.14/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.FileStorage) class. refer to [api](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.files), you cannot use `with open(uploadmedia, 'rb') as file:` .

try using stream attribute :

```
uploadmedia = request.files['fileupload']
client = Client('thisismykey')
new_upload = client.uploads('<space-id>').create(uploadmedia.stream)
```

Comment: I don't think the stream attribute needs to be accessed as FileStorage is a proxy to the stream. Stream methods should be accessible on the FileStorage instance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried as you asked and while it does 'do something' (which is already an improvement on what I've been trying for the last 3 days haha) on Contentful, which is create a new entry in the Media tab where this is supposed to go, [the actual file isn't being uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdR3x.png) (the page is stuck on `Loading`).

Comment: I don't know why it stucked in the loading are there any errors . then can you try `uploadmedia.read()`

Comment: My bad, I needed to initiate another call for the API. Your answer works fine for what the question was, thank you!!